# Is Dispatcher an object you can pass in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is the Dispatcher an object that you can pass in C#? I have one thread that calls another thread. The second thread gives me this error when I try to do Dispatcher.CheckAccess():

> An object reference is requied for the non-static field, method or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()'.

So I try to create a dispatcher object in the original class and pass it to the second class, but the program doesn't like that and crashes.

The code has the general structure:

```
public public partial class MainView : UserControl{
  public myButtonClick(Event eventObj, Session session)
  {
  //does some stuff and invokes Dispatcher.CheckAccess()
  secondClass.startProcess(passThruString);
  }
}
public class SecondClass
{
  public startProcess(string passThru){
  //does some other stuff and calls Dispatcher.CheckAccess() which throws error
  }
}
```

I have corrected the error by replacing Dispatcher.CheckAccess() with Dispatcher.Currentdispatcher.CheckAccess(), but why can't I just create a dispatcher object?

Comment: Can you show your code and the exception that you are getting?

Comment: Please see my overall code outline above.

Comment: It is difficult to help you solve your problem when you don't provide your code as-is in an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, but the original code is several thousand lines and has tons of event handlers and multiple files.

Comment: My question isn't really about my code, though. It's more about why I can't create and reference an object of the Dispatcher.

Comment: That's where the word "minimal" in MVCE comes from - reduce the problem to just the relevant code. Or, come up with a working example that reproduces the problem in less code. The code you've posted attempts this, but leaves a lot of guess work for people helping you, which generally makes answering questions more difficult.

Comment: I'll attempt an answer since I _think_ I know what you're trying to do...

Comment: You can't create a Dispatcher because it has no public constructors. Now as to why MS designed it that way, we can only guess. From looking at the source code, I suspect that they wanted to cache instances because each dispatcher instance hooks the native windows message loop. To get a dispatcher instance you use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` or `Dispatcher.FromThread`. In the case of UserControl, there is a property, Dispatcher that can be used to access the associated Dispatcher object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dispatcher can be passed around just like any other object in C#. However, a dispatcher can't be constructed because the constructor is made private:

```
var dispatcher = new Dispatcher(); //compile error
```

To pass a dispatcher around, you need to get some other already existing dispatcher. One option (as you noted in your updated question) is to use `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`:

```
var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
SomeFunction(dispatcher);
```

This creates a reference to `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` which can be stored and passed around.

In one of my own projects, I use a dispatcher to avoid errors like "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it". This is because in this particular class I have, it is possible for a background thread to attempt to do an operation on an object created on the UI thread. I am guessing you have a similar issue.

Here is a minimal example of how I use it:

```
public class SomeClass
{
  private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

  public SomeClass()
  {
    _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
  }

  public void SomeOperation()
  {
    InvokeIfNeeded(() => Console.WriteLine("Something"));
  }

  private void InvokeIfNeeded(Action action)
  {
    if (_dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
      _dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    else
      action();
  }
}
```

This may not be the best way to use Dispatchers, but it demonstrates how you can store a reference to it as a field, just like other objects in C#.

Comment: Instead of comparing threads, you can just call `CheckAccess()`, that's exactly what it's for.

Comment: Thank you! That was the exact explanation that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, to call `CheckAccess()` you need an instance of `Dispatcher` on the left side of the dot. For example, a code like this would work:

```
Dispatcher dispatcher = /* something here */;
dispatcher.CheckAccess();
```

This explains why simply writing `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` in `SecondClass` doesn't work. But then why *does* it work in `MainView`? Because it inherits from `UserControl`, which has a property called `Dispatcher`. So, when you write `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` there, it's basically a shorter way of writing:

```
UserControl control = this;
control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess();
```

Ok, so now you should understand why `MainView` works and why `SecondClass` doesn't. The only question that remains: how to make `SecondClass` work? What you need to do is to get access to an instance of `Dispatcher`. But to answer that, I need to ask a question of you: *Why* are you trying to call `CheckAccess()`?

Generally, you should do this when you want to call a method on a `Dispatcher`-bound object and you don't know if you're on the right thread for that. But if you're in that situation, you don't need *a* `Dispatcher`, you need *the* `Dispatcher` that's associated with the object you're trying to access. And to get that, you should use the `Dispatcher` property of that object (the same property that caused the confusion above).

If you're doing something else, the answer might be different, but it's hard for me to guess what that would be.